# Task from java web services and XML

Tags: java, xml, web-services

This is the task from java web services and XML:

Create a translation service.

Customer service to activate the service method as follows:

getWord ("automobil", "russian", "polish")

The first parameter is the required word, the second is the original language, and the third target language.

The method should return a string with the appropriate word or words separated by commas if there are synonyms.

Data source, the service should use XML documents (the system may have only a few words, in order to test the functionality).

This is the java doc:

```
package xmlparsiranje;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import org.w3c.dom.Node;

import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import java.io.File;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Xmlparsiranje {



    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

     // try {

        File fXmlFile = new File("C:\\zaTestiranje.xml");

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                Scanner word = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println("Input word: ");

String rijec = word.nextLine();

                Scanner izvoriste = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println("Izvorni: ");

String izvorni = izvoriste.nextLine();
                Scanner Odrediste = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println("Odrediste: ");


String odredisni = Odrediste.nextLine();

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("word");


 // System.out.println(odredisni);


        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
 Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
 Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

           NodeList engleski = eElement.getElementsByTagName("english");
           NodeList ruski = eElement.getElementsByTagName("russian");
           NodeList poljski = eElement.getElementsByTagName("polish");                    

          // System.out.println(engleski.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());  

          if (odredisni.equals("english"))
          {
              if(izvorni.equals("russian")){
                  if(ruski.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent().equals(rijec))
                          {           
              System.out.println(ruski.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
              System.out.println(engleski.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
                          }
                                            }  
              if(izvorni.equals("polish"))  {
                   if(poljski.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent().equals(rijec)) {
              System.out.println(poljski.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
              System.out.println(engleski.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
                                            }   
          }
          }
           if (odredisni.equals("russian"))
          {
              if(izvorni.equals("english")){
                  if(engleski.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent().equals(rijec))
                          {           
              System.out.println(engleski.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
              System.out.println(ruski.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
                          }
                                            }  
              if(izvorni.equals("polish"))  {
                   if(poljski.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent().equals(rijec)) {
              System.out.println(poljski.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
              System.out.println(ruski.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
                                            }   
          }
          }

            if (odredisni.equals("polish"))
          {
              if(izvorni.equals("english")){
                  if(engleski.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent().equals(rijec))
                          {           
              System.out.println(engleski.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
              System.out.println(poljski.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
                          }
                                            }  
              if(izvorni.equals("russian"))  {
                   if(poljski.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent().equals(rijec)) {
              System.out.println(poljski.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
              System.out.println(ruski.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
                                            }   
          }
          }

            /*  String trazenaRijec = getTagValue("english", eElement);
              String engleski = getTagValue("english", eElement); 
              String ruski = getTagValue("russian", eElement);   
              String poljski = getTagValue("polish", eElement);   
              if (odredisni.equals(engleski))
              {
                 System.out.println("Engleski : " + getTagValue("english", eElement)); 
              }
               if (odredisni.equals(ruski))
              {
                 System.out.println("Ruski : " + getTagValue("russian", eElement)); 
              }
                if (odredisni.equals(poljski))
              {
                 System.out.println("Poljski : " + getTagValue("polish", eElement)); 
              } */




             /* System.out.println("English : " + getTagValue("english", eElement));

              System.out.println("Russian : " + getTagValue("russian", eElement));

                      System.out.println("Polish : " + getTagValue("polish", eElement));*/







           }



     // } catch (Exception e) {

       // e.printStackTrace();



  }



  private static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {

    NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();



        Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);



    return nValue.getNodeValue();

  }



}
```

And this is XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<translate>
<word>
 <english>Car</english>
 <russian>Avtomobil</russian>
 <polish>Samochod</polish>
</word>
<word>
<english>Love</english>
<russian>Lobite</russian>
<polish>milosc</polish>
</word>
<word>
<english>Busy</english>
<russian>Zanimate</russian>
<polish>Zajety</polish>
</word>
</translate>
```

It didnt get accepted by the instructor. He says there is no service. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to develop a webservice not a console application

Comment: Even if this is a handler for service requests, you are doing it terribly wrong. Change your XML structure to support XPaths and Lookups.